# Creating live tile effect on iOS

Tags: ios

How can I create (Windows8 like) live tile effect on a button or a frame? 
I want to show some text randomly changed in a button. Fade in and fade out effects would be nice.

Comment: What did you try until know ?

Comment: It is a new idea for me. I couldn't find any component for this.

Comment: UICollectionView is what you need ...

Comment: " Fade in and fade out effects would be nice." so you want us to program it for you. Cause that is a request.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to animate objects. I expect to find some clues or libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer to this question is very hard, since this is basic iOS knowledge and there are multiple solutions to the problem.**

What I would do to solve this problem:

1. Create custom a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass which would represent a tile.

   ```
   @interface UITileView : UICollectionViewCell

   @property (nonatomic, weak) id<UITileViewDataSource> dataSource;

   - (void)reloadTile;

   @end
   ```
2. Create subclasses of the `UICollectionViewCell` class created in 1. that represent specific tiles.
3. Create a `UICollectionView`, that would display those `UICollectionViewCell`'s.
4. Create a delegate/datasource architecture, to provide tiles with data or specific subviews.

   ```
   @protocol UITileViewDataSource

   - (UIImage *)tileView imageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
   - (NSString *)tileView tileStringForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

   @end
   ```
5. Animate the tile with `UIView` `animateWithDuration:` method (`alpha` property for fade in and fade out).

   ```
   // Fade in
   mySpecificTile.alpha = 0.0f;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
   {
       mySpecificTile.alpha = 1.0f;
   }
   ```

*This is probably the fastest and easiest solution. You can create a better scalable solution of course.* Just make sure the tiles do not own the data and ask the data source for it.

**This is only a concept and should serve as a guideline on how to proceed.**

Read the following links for more information on `UICollectionView`:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html
- http://nshipster.com/uicollectionview/

*All the code written here is ARC only!*

Comment: Thank you for describing steps. I will try something.

Comment: Wouldn't your solution make more sense to create UICollectionViewCell subclasses? :)

Comment: Yes it does, was in the process of editing the solution. :)